# Not sure how to handle this linq query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

So I'm trying to use a linq query to clean up my code a bit. Right now I've got an array of the file extensions I'm looking for..

```
string[] fileExt = { ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx" };
```

and here is what I'm trying to do with it.

```
fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName, "*.*").Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pdf") || s.EndsWith(".docx") || s.EndsWith(".doc"));  /*look into cleaning this up with LINQ*/
```

I've tried several approaches but I'm not really understanding how this works.
To clarify, that line above works, but I'm told there's a more efficient way to do it with linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilise the [any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
 string[] fileExt = { ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx" };

 fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName, "*.*")
                     .Where(s => fileExt.Any(ext => s.EndsWith(ext)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about .Any so I was trying to do it with nested queries and it just made things more difficult